# Subgroup Lattice of $G = Z^*_{26}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I have been looking through my textbook and have noticed subgroup lattices. I understand the premise of them under addition, but this one example, in particular, I can't figure out.
Let $G = Z^*_{26}$. I know the order of $G$ is $12$ with $7$ being a generator of $G$.

Am I just testing the length of every element when doing $(1,a,a^2,a^3,....)$ and whatever the length of the element is would be included in that particular level of the lattice?

Hopefully, that makes sense and I would appreciate any feedback

Comment: The group of units is also denoted by $U(26)$ and has $\phi(26)=12$ elements. It is a cyclic group, so to each divisor of $12$ there is exactly one subgroup.

Comment: @DietrichBurde so the lattice would only show the values $(1,2,3,4,6,12)$?

Comment: Sorry, I interchanged $\phi(26)=12$ and $26$ here, but it works the same. Yes, $d\mid 12$ says that $d=1,2,3,4,6,12$.